# EntityFramework 4.1 DbContext select adding CAST columns with additional characters

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

i'm doing a standard GetAll() from dbcontext:

```
 DbContext.Set<T>()
```

however i'm getting a weird message from oracle:

> {"ORA-00904: \"Extent1\".\"Sub_Object_ID\": invalid identifier"}

if i look at generated sql (by looking at the query variable), i see that a few variables are added at the end as CASTS

```
"Extent1"."SomeEntity_ID",                            <-- correct
"Extent1"."SomeEnttiy2_ID",                           <-- correct
"Extent1"."Sub_Object",                               <-- correct

CAST( "Extent1"."SomeEntity_ID1" AS number(10,0)) AS "C3",  <-- "1" appended
CAST( "Extent1"."SomeEnttiy2_ID1" AS number(10,0)) AS "C4", <-- "1" appended
CAST( "Extent1"."Sub_Object_ID" AS number(10,0)) AS "C5",   <-- "_ID" appended
...
FROM "dbo"."MyEntity" "Extent1"
```

all the properties were correctly identified in the main portion of the select.  however in the CAST portion, property names were appended with digits and _ID.. this is causing the select to fail..

looking at my entity, i have the properties specified once.. in this format:

```
    public Nullable<decimal> SomeEntity_ID { get; set; }
```

what's with the casts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was just a matter of configuring foreign keys. I still don't understand the intention of this default behavior (adding a set of select columns for every foreign with appended "1")..

but declaring foreign keys fixes it.

via fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FirmPerson>()
    .HasRequired(f => f.Firm)
    .WithMany(p => p.FirmPerson)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.FirmID);
```

or via attribute:

```
    public int FirmID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FirmID")]
    public virtual Firm Foo { get; set; }
```